# WebDriver Change ComboBox Selection "webkit-user-select"

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium, webdriver

I tried to modify the combobox selection of a "webkit-user-select" type by various means but it would never work.

1)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#BirthMonth")); // Exception
select.selectByValue("July"); // Select item by value

org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"
```

2)

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#BirthMonth"));
element.click(); // Open comboBox
element.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN); // Navigate down (Exception)

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

3)
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\":9\"]")); // Select item October directly (Exception)

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element
```

HTML:

```
<label id="month-label" class="month">
  <span id="BirthMonth" class=" " aria-invalid="false"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" aria-expanded="false" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" title="Birthday" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption">July</div><div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</div></div><div class="goog-menu goog-menu-vertical" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" style="-webkit-user-select: none; visibility: visible; left: 0px; top: -158.5px; display: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":0" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">January</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">February</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":2" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">March</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":3" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">April</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":4" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">May</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":5" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">June</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":6" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">July</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":7" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">August</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":8" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">September</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":9" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">October</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":a" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">November</div></div><div class="goog-menuitem" role="option" id=":b" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-menuitem-content" style="-webkit-user-select: none;">December</div></div></div><input type="hidden" name="BirthMonth" id="HiddenBirthMonth" value="07"></span>
  </label>
```

The 2nd solution seems to partially work since the combobox is opened but navigating using the up / down keys won't succeed (not even with the Actions class, same exception).

Comment: Well it isn't a normal `select`. The error says so. It's a bunch of `div`'s and `span`'s styled together to make it look like a dropdown. I suspect just a simple `.findElement` and get the `span` you need (by text, so using XPath) will work

Comment: Please suggest code for setting a specific month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Purus is correct, since your combo box is a span, you cannot use the `Select` wrapper as it can only be used on `select` tagname.

I think what you were trying to do was right, click on the combo, that opens up the months then click on the appropriate month. Did you try something like this,

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#BirthMonth"));
 element.click();
 WebElement month = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//div[text()='July']")));
      month.click();
```

Comment: Works perfectly, awesome! I didn't think of waiting like that and good xpath suggestion

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza Glad it worked for you. I remembered going through a similar select box nightmare when WebDriver was in beta version few years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, the element should be of <select> tag. But in your case, its a span element. So its obvious that the identification fails.

The rendered element in your browser may look like a select or combo box. But in the world of HTML, Selenium sees it as a SPAN element.

The below HTML code has select element.

```
<select id="testid" name ="testname>
<option selected="" value="a">a</option>
<option selected="" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Selenium Code is as below.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#testid"));
select.selectByValue("a"); // Select item by value
```

With JavaScript, try the below.

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id(":9"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but what would be the correct way of dealing with spans then? There's no Span class or similar AFAIK

Comment: You have to form your own way of handling them as there is no specific method available to deal with SPAN.